# Excel automation, how to detect if user runs macro in excel worksheet or clicks 'Run Macro' CommandBarControl?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, vsto

Is there some event in the .net automation libraries that can detect when the user who is working on the excel file, has run a macro?

For example, the user opens an excel document which contains an macro, than he runs the macro and the .net application, that is attached to that excel process detect the start macro event?

or maybe bind the macro function to a delegated event in the application..

**edit:**

**Can the 'Run Macro' CommandBarControl click event be caught from the code  behind?**

Comment: There are no built-in events that get triggered in excel when a macro is run. The macro would need to set some kind of "flag" which could be picked up by your .Net code.

Comment: you can review [this](http://blogs.officezealot.com/charles/archive/2004/12/10/3574.aspx) link. It shows you how to "know" the Windows user which is working with the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Bross the question is re when a user runs a macro, not detecting the user. The flag method makes sense - unless you need to detect the user without the user knowing and the user has access to the code and can understand what the flga does

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, you saved me good amount of time going in the wrong direction. Next thing i would try using Reflection. If something good comes out, I'll share it here.

Comment: Any Macro or a particular Macro?

Comment: well any macro created, since it is possible to get all macro's names in the code behind, and method signatures.

Comment: Something like this? http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-3307/Trying-access-macro-C.htm

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is 'an event' in the `.NET` automation but I know [TrackToAct.com](http://tracktoact.com/blog/) (full disclosure my co.) has a `VBA` code snippet or `DLL` that your drop into track events. It enables you to tag events and report on the usage via web dashboard.

Comment: nice app. But I'm trying to figure out this, without changing the code in the macro..

Answer (score 1):

Having never done this myself, I can't say for sure how you would define that specific application event, but this page here gave me some useful information on defining your own events through class modules. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

edit: The whole page is on events, to read about defining your own scroll down about 4/5 of the way.